# Render a different view from any controller in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, book and course. In the books_controller I have a search method to find books by their ISBN.

```
def searchbook
  @searchedbook = Book.find_by_isbn(params[:q])
end
```

There is an input field in the index page that displays all the books. So my index.html.erb has this:

```
=form_tag({controller: "books", action: "searchbook"}, :method => :get) do
 .search_field
   %p
    Search Using ISBN:
   =text_field_tag :q
   =button_tag 'Go' , class: 'search-button' , type: :submit
%br
```

I have added this to my routes:

```
match 'searchbook', to: 'books#searchbook', via: :get
```

I just realized that my searchbook.html.erb is exactly the same as the show.html.erb. How can I get show.html.erb to render the results from searchbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have same action for searchbook page view and form submit, so you need to check params `q` at URL  `searchbook` action. So, whenever you submit the form, it will append parameter `q` and  `@searchedbook`

```
def searchbook
  @searchedbook = Book.find_by_isbn(params[:q]) if params[:q].present?
end
```

At `searchbook.html.erb`

```
-if @searchedbook
  = render "show" # render the show partial
```

Comment: I just got this error: 
'Missing partial books/_show, application/_show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/qqq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/qqq/Documents/com381/bookiit/app/views" ' I wonder if it means that I should rename my show to _show

Comment: @neesop, you need a erb partial file at books directroy like `_show.html.erb`. If a have a file like `show.html.erb` than rename it to `_show.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [partials](http://richonrails.com/articles/partials-in-ruby-on-rails) are designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Use partials in `searchbook.html.erb` like `render "show"`.